# Staging Server Database Not Connecting

Tags: database, multi-environment

I've moved my site to the staging server but now I'm getting a craft can't connect to the database with credentials in craft/config/db.php

Thing is I uploaded this script with the same credentials and it connects just fine. Any idea what I could be doing wrong

```
<?php
# Fill our vars and run on cli
# $ php -f db-connect-test.php
$dbname = 'name';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");
​
echo "connected to the database";
```

My full db.php file with actual db creds removed - updated to include domain from live site.

```
<?php
​
/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's database configuration settings go in here.
 * You can see a list of the default settings in craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php
 */
​
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    ),
    'nec.dev' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'database' => 'nec',
    ),
    'nec.dev.stagingdomain.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'staging-user',
        'password' => 'staging-password',
        'database' => 'staging-database',
    ),
    'nec-inc.com' => array(
        'server' => 'localhost',
        'user' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
    ),
);
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work on staging when the same credentials work with the connection testing script.

Comment: The domain you're getting the error on is nec.dev.stagingdomain.com?

Comment: @BradBell yes. Updating snippet with new, still non working code, based on a response in slack

Comment: The staging url seems strange. Would `'nec.stagingdomain.com' => array(...)` work?

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I realized I had the staging subdomains in the wrong order. it should be dev.nec.stagingdomaain.com now all working

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if you've sorted thing out (`dev.nec...` vs `nec.dev...`)

In general, I find the domain name matching in the config files to be confusing and error prone. I always follow the advice in the [Foolproof Multi-Environment Config](http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/210) recipe. Put this at the top of your index.php:

```
switch (strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
  case 'nec.dev':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'DEV');
    break;
  case 'nec.dev.stagingdomain.com':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'STAGE');
    break;
  case 'nec-inc.com':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'LIVE');
    break;
  default:
    exit('No environment defined for '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}
```

Then your db.php and general.php will look like this:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(...),
  'DEV' => array(...),
  'STAGE' => array(...),
  'LIVE' => array(...),
);
```

And when you hit `dev.nec.stagingdomain.com` you will see that *No environment defined* error and fairly quickly see what is wrong.

(There is also an [Enhanced Foolproof Multi-Environment Config](http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/273) recipe)